# General purpose registers of ARM microcontroller Doubts

Tags: arm

I am a new-commer to the field of ARM micro-controllers and i was studying about and have the following doubt:

1. Are General purpose registers of ARM a part of its SRAM or not?

Answer (score 1):

No, they're not, they're registers within the processor itself (which may be implemented in SRAM,) but they don't have addresses within the memory map.